# Back Button with Multiple Sources

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Within my app, I want to create a user profile controller, which can be navigated to from several different controllers. I would like it to have a back button that will take the user back to whichever controller they came from.

How do I do this?

Comment: Thats the default behaviour of a `UINavigationController`

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462

Read some article like this on how to implement navigation in Swift.

Comment: @CraigSiemens I've done that before with a simple navigation hierachy, but in this case the multiple views that can lead to the ProfileController aren't really related. Don't they all need to be under the same NavigationController hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dismiss

Add `UIButton` for back navigation somewhere to your `UserProfileController`. Then in `UserProfileController` create action and set it as action of your button. This action dismisses your `UserProfileController` (so you get back to previous `UIViewController`)

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

## UINavigationController

Alternatively you can have previous `ViewControllers` embed in `UINavigationController`. Then you will be able to tap to **back button** (which is set by default) in `UINavigationBar` which gets you to previous `UIViewController`

Comment: exactly. just dismiss the controller and it will go back to the same controller it came from.

Comment: After playing around with both options, I ended up embedding each "source" controller into it's own separate NavigationController.